# "Send now" emails going to wrong contact

Tags: wordpress, email, 4.7.14

A few times, including this morning, we have used the send now feature for 20-40 contacts who matched a search and Civi has mixed up the contact parameters. What often happens is that a contact is sent pre-filled information for the preceding contact in the list.

I think this happens when we select all, then choose `action > email (send now)` and then remove a contact from the list by clicking the "x" beside their name in the "to" field. But I am not certain.

Has anyone seen this happen to them? Is it a bug or are we doing something wrong?

We are running civi 4.7.14 and wordpress 4.7

Comment: have not had any reports from our users of such an outcome - you 'may' be able to replicate on demo by opting to 'print pdf letter' since demo won't send out emails, and in that way you may see the immediate outcome of testing. not sure but may be worth a bit of time to see if that helps you find a way to 'replicate'

Comment: Do you have any updates / Did you manage to resolve this issue? We might be able to help still if you provide more info...